# Pygame how to get 'custom boundaries'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-requests

I have been coding in python for about 4 months now and I want to get into pygame. But I have been noticing there isn't really a way to get a custom boundary for collisions, eg. Have a car shaped boundary instead of a rectangle. Is there way to get custom boundaries? thanks

Comment: Here's [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871398/6220679) without sprites. And search for tutorials about [masks](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) and pixel perfect collision detection.

Comment: @skrx thanks alot, I'll follow up on it

Comment: You're welcome! You could also check out [Pymunk](http://pymunk.org/) (the physics library) which allows you to combine multiple polygons to create more complex shapes, but it takes a while (and can be a bit difficult) to familiarize yourself with this lib.