# Pygame collision with masks

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, mask

I have made a putt-putt game and now I want to add a slanted wall type. Because of this, I need to use masks for the collision (until now I have just used rects). I have spent hours learning about masks and trying to figure out why my code won't work. There are no errors, the collision just isn't detected.

I have simplified my code down to something much smaller just as a way for me to test it efficiently. From everything I've seen this seems like it should work, but it doesnt. Here it is:

```py
import pygame

# Pygame init stuff
pygame.init()

wind_width = 1200
wind_height = 700

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((wind_width, wind_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Mini Golf!")

pygame.display.update()

gameExit = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Class setups
class Ball:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.image = pygame.image.load("sball.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def render(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Slant:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.image = pygame.image.load("posslant.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

    def render(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
        gameDisplay.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# Creating objects
ball = Ball(250, 250)

slant = Slant(270, 250)

# Game loop
gameExit = False
while not(gameExit):

    # Moves ball
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ball.y -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ball.y += 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ball.x -= 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ball.x += 1

    # Collision detection
    offset_x, offset_y = (slant.rect.x - ball.rect.x), (slant.rect.y - ball.rect.y)
    if slant.mask.overlap(ball.mask, (offset_x, offset_y)):
        print("hit")

    # Draws everything
    gameDisplay.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ball.render()
    slant.render()

    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(100)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Do you use transparent pixels in your images? I guess you should call `convert_alpha()` on your surfaces (e.g.: `self.image = pygame.image.load("sball.png").convert_alpha()`), but I can't say for sure without having your images.

Comment: My images are transparent so I didnt think I would need to do any converting

Comment: I just tried using ```covert_alpha()``` and it did not seem to change anything

Comment: Maybe have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862739/sprite-mask-collision-problems-in-pygame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offset parameter of the method [`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) is the relative position of the *`othermask`* in relation to the [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object.
So the offset is calculated by subtracting the coordinates of `slant` from the coordinates of `ball`:

<s>`offset_x, offset_y = (slant.rect.x - ball.rect.x), (slant.rect.y - ball.rect.y)`</s>

```py
offset = (ball.rect.x - slant.rect.x), (ball.rect.y - slant.rect.y)
if slant.mask.overlap(ball.mask, offset):
    print("hit")
```

---

When you create the mask images, then I recommend to ensure that the image has per pixel alpha format by calling [`.convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha):

```py
class Ball:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.image = pygame.image.load("sball.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image.convert_alpha()) # <---
```

```py
class Slant:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.image = pygame.image.load("posslant.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image.image.convert_alpha()) # <---
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceMaskIntersect](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceMaskIntersect#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

See also: [Mask](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_mask.md)

Comment: That makes sense, but still does not fix the code. I still never get the print statement. Thanks for the help nonetheless.

Comment: Strange. Could it have something to do with my images than? They are both .png. I have uploaded them here: https://imgur.com/a/byjGC8M

Comment: @LoganHolmes The bit depth of the white rectangle was 24. I restored it with a depth of 32 and it works: https://imgur.com/NwRVnad. But you can fix this by calling  `.convert_alpha()`. See the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. I have been stuck on this for so long. I can't thank you enough for taking all the time to help me.