# Using mask for collision detection pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game where your supposed to land the player on a surface. I have named this surface as 'lander'. Here is my player class:

```
class player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        self.ufo = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\lander\ufo.png")
        self.ufo = pygame.transform.scale(self.ufo, (height, width))
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = 0
        self.score = 0

    def draw(self):
        g.screen.blit(self.ufo, (self.x, self.y))

    def fly_up(self):
        self.speed = 5
        p.y = p.y -4
        self.y -= self.speed

    def fly_right(self):
        self.speed = 5
        p.y = p.y -4
        self.x += self.speed

    def fly_left(self):
        self.speed = 5
        p.y = p.y -4
        self.x -= self.speed
```

Here is my lander class:

```
class lander:
        def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = (192, 192, 192)

        def draw(self):
            self.lander = pygame.draw.rect(g.screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


        def move(self):
            self.speed = 4
            self.x -= self.speed

        def lander_off_screen(self):
            if self.x == 0 - p.height - 50:
                self.x = 1200 + p.height + 50
                self.y = random.randint(230, 590)
```

I want to detect if they are colliding using masks. However I am having a couple of problems.
Firstly I dont know how to convert `self.lander` to alpha. It gave me an error when I tried.
Even when I used an actual image instead of a rectange as lander, it didnt work like I
I wanted it to. 
Thanks

My code so far for reference is here:

```
import pygame
import os
import random
import time

os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
pygame.init()

start = time.time()

def main():
    class game:
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self.win = pygame.display
            self.SH = 600
            self.SW = 1200
            self.screen = self.win.set_mode((self.SW, self.SH))
            self.win.set_caption("UFO Lander")
            self.white = (255, 255, 255)
            self.red = (255, 0, 0)
            self.green = (0, 255, 0)
            self.transparent =  (0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.background = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\lander\background.png")
            self.background = pygame.transform.scale(self.background, (self.SW, self.SH))
            self.transparent =  (0, 0, 0, 0)
            clock = pygame.time.Clock()
            self.FPS = 30
            self.FPS = clock.tick(self.FPS)
            self.gravity = 4
            self.time_passed = pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000

        def write(self, text, color, x , y, size):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Aerial", size)
            text = font.render(text, True, color)
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            self.screen.blit(text,(x , y))

        def player_off_screen(self):
            if p.x < 0:
                p.x = 0
                g.write("YOU CRASHED!!", self.red, 50, 250, 200)
                g.win.update()
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                main()

            if p.x + p.height > 1200:
                p.x = 1200 - p.height
                g.write("YOU CRASHED!!", self.red, 50, 250, 200)
                g.win.update()
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                main()

            if p.y < 0:
                p.y = 0
                g.write("YOU CRASHED!!", self.red, 50, 250, 200)
                g.win.update()
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                main()

            if p.y + p.width > 600:
                p.y = 600 - p.width
                g.write("YOU CRASHED!!", self.red, 50, 250, 200)
                g.win.update()
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                main()

    class thrust:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.thrust = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\lander\thrust.png")
            self.thrust = pygame.transform.scale(self.thrust, (100, 150))
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

        def draw(self):
            g.screen.blit(self.thrust, (self.x, self.y))

        def update_x(self, variable):
            self.x = p.x + variable

        def update_y(self, variable):
            self.y = p.y + variable

    class player:
        def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
            self.ufo = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Documents\A level python codes\lander\ufo.png")
            self.ufo = pygame.transform.scale(self.ufo, (height, width))
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.speed = 0
            self.score = 0

        def draw(self):
            g.screen.blit(self.ufo, (self.x, self.y))

        def fly_up(self):
            self.speed = 5
            p.y = p.y -4
            self.y -= self.speed

        def fly_right(self):
            self.speed = 5
            p.y = p.y -4
            self.x += self.speed

        def fly_left(self):
            self.speed = 5
            p.y = p.y -4
            self.x -= self.speed

    p = player(100, 100, 350, 150)
    t = thrust(p.x, p.y)
    t2 = thrust(p.x, p.y)

    class obstacles:pass

    class lander:
        def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.color = (192, 192, 192)

        def draw(self):
            self.lander = pygame.draw.rect(g.screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


        def move(self):
            self.speed = 4
            self.x -= self.speed

        def lander_off_screen(self):
            if self.x == 0 - p.height - 50:
                self.x = 1200 + p.height + 50
                self.y = random.randint(230, 590)

    class fuel:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 100
            self.y = 60
            self.height = 30
            self.width = 300

        def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(g.screen, g.white, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

        def less_fuel(self):
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or (pygame.K_UP) or (pygame.K_LEFT):
                    self.change = 0.7
                    self.width -= self.change

        def run_out(self):
            if self.width < 0:
                g.write("FUEL EMPTY!!", g.red, 50, 250, 200)
                g.win.update()
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                main()

    f = fuel()


    class menu: pass

    g = game()


    run = True
    t = thrust(p.x, p.y)
    l = lander(1200 - p.height - 50, random.randint(230, 590), 20, p.height+ 50)
    while run:
        g.screen.blit(g.background, (0, 0))

        l.draw()
        l.move()

        g.write("s", g.white, 350, 10, 50)
        g.write("Fuel: ", g.white ,10, 60, 50)
        g.write("Score: %d" %(p.score), g.white, 1000, 10, 50)

        p.draw()
        p.y += g.gravity

        g.player_off_screen()
        l.lander_off_screen()

        t.update_x(50)
        t.update_y(110)
        t2.update_x(200)
        t2.update_y(110)

        f.draw()
        f.run_out()

        try:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

            f.less_fuel()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    p.fly_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    p.fly_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    t.draw()
                    t2.draw()
                    p.fly_up()

            end = time.time()
            duration = end - start
            g.write("Total game time: %d" %(duration), g.white ,10, 10, 50)

        except NameError:
            pass

        pygame.display.flip()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: in most situations using normal `pygame.Rect` to check collision can be enough. BTW: If you will keep position and size in `pygame.Rect` then you can use `p.rect.right == 600` instead of `p.x == 600 - p.widht`. And then you can use standard method `lander.rect.colliderect(player.rect)`

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - i.e `class Player` similar to `pygame.Rect`, `pygame.surface.Surface`, `pygame.time.Clock` - it helps to recognize class in code - ie. `player = Player()`. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) with the size of the rectangle rather than drawing a rectangle:

```py
class lander:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        # [...]

        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill((192, 192, 192))

        def draw(self):
            self.lander = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.y))
            g.screen.blit(self.image, self.lander)
```

Use [`pygame.mask.from_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface) to create a [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) object from a *Surface*:

```py
class player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        # [...]

        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ufo)
```

```py
class lander:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        # [...]

        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

Use [`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) to detect the collision of masks. The offset parameter of the method [`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) is the relative position of the *`othermask`* in relation to the [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object.
In the following `p` is an instance of `player` and `l` is an instance of `lander`. So the offset is calculated by subtracting the coordinates of `p` from the coordinates of `l`:

```py
offset = (l.x - p.x), (l.y - p.y)
if p.mask.overlap(l.mask, offset):
    print("hit")
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceMaskIntersect](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SurfaceMaskIntersect#main.py)</kbd>

See also: [Mask](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_mask.md) and [Pygame collision with masks is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks-is-not-working/57499484#57499484)