# PyGame pixel perfect collision not registering at the correct place

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to test the collision between a platform and the player. These platforms are images with a rhumbas, so regular rectangle collision won't work very well. The code down below starts printing true when the player is at the top left of the screen, but not where the platform actually is. I don't see what I am doing wrong so any help is appreciated.

```py
for i in range(len(self.platforms)):
    # Masks
    feet_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.feet.convert_alpha())
    platform_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.platforms[i][4].convert_alpha())
    # Images
    feet_rect = self.feet.get_rect()
    platform_rect = self.platforms[i][4].get_rect()
    feet_rect.topleft = (self.feet_rect[0], self.feet_rect[1])
    platform_rect.topleft = (self.platforms[i][0], self.platforms[i][1])
    offset_x, offset_y = (platform_rect.left - feet_rect.left), (platform_rect.top - feet_rect.top)

    if platform_mask.overlap(feet_mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None:
        print('true')
        break
```

Comment: Related [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039) and [Pygame collision with masks is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks-is-not-working/57499484#57499484)

Answer (score 1):

the coumputation of the offset is wrong. The offset parameter of the method [`overlap()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) is the relative position of the *`othermask`* in relation to the [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object.
So the offset is calculated by subtracting the coordinates of `feet_rect` from the coordinates of `platform_rect`:

<s>`offset_x, offset_y = (platform_rect.left - feet_rect.left), (platform_rect.top - feet_rect.top)`</s>

```py
offset_x, offset_y = (feet_rect.left, platform_rect.left), (feet_rect.top, platform_rect.top)
if platform_mask.overlap(feet_mask, (offset_x, offset_y)) != None:
    print('true')
    break
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but when I do this it still prints true at position where the sprites are not colliding, but instead of the top left it is the bottom right. Is this a problem somewhere else in my code not related to the collision?

Comment: @Farmer Who knows? I just can see the short snippet of your code. In this snippet is the bug which I've spotted in my answer. The rest of the code looks fine as far as I can see.

Comment: Alright, thank you for helping, it is greatly appreciated.