# pygame - mask collision not working, return always same collision point

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, offset, mask

I'm trying to create a pixel-perfect collision but if I try to print the collision value, I always get that the collision is on point (8, 0). this is my code, thank you.

```
collisionsroom1 = pygame.image.load("images/collisionsroom1.png")
characterhitbox = pygame.image.load("images/characterhitbox.png")

def collision():
  mouseposx, mouseposy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
  ROOTwidth, ROOTheight = pygame.display.get_surface().get_size()

  #room 1 collision
  collisionsroom1 = pygame.transform.scale(collisionsroom1, (ROOTwidth/2.3, ROOTheight))
  ROOT.blit(collisionsroom1, [ROOTwidth/2-room1_width/2,0])
  collisionsroom1_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(collisionsroom1)

  #character hitbox
  characterhitbox = pygame.transform.scale(characterhitbox, (ROOTheight/30, ROOTheight/30))
  characterhitbox_width = characterhitbox.get_width()
  characterhitbox_height = characterhitbox.get_height()
  ROOT.blit(characterhitbox, [mouseposx-characterhitbox_width/2, mouseposy- 
  characterhitbox_height/2])

  while True:
     mouseposx, mouseposy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

     #get character updated mask position
     ROOT.blit(characterhitbox, [mouseposx-characterhitbox_width/2, mouseposy- 
     characterhitbox_height/2])
     characterhitbox_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(characterhitbox)

     #room collisions
     offset = 0, 0

     collision = characterhitbox_mask.overlap(collisionsroom1_mask, offset)

     print (collision)
     if collision:
        print("yescollision")
     else:
        print("nocollision")
```

Comment: It cant work, because of `offset = 0, 0`. The offset must be the distance between the top left corners of the images.

Comment: I suspect that it's the offset's fault, but i can't understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [PyGame collision with masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks/57499484#57499484). Your code can't work, because of `offset = 0, 0`. The offset must be the distance between the top left corners of the images:

```py
offset = (character_x - room_x), (charcater_y - room_y)
collision = characterhitbox_mask.overlap(collisionsroom1_mask, offset)
```

In the example above, (`room_x`, `room_y`) is the position of the room and (`character_x`, `character_y`) is the position of the character.