# How can I make a mask for a rect?

Tags: pygame, mask, rect

Can I make a mask of a rect, if so, how? I'm trying to make collisions between a mask and a rect, and since I can't make a rect of a mask(No pixel perfect collision then) I figured I'd ask if I could make a mask of a rect? Like given the dimensions and x/y positon of a rect, how could I make a mask based on that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object and set all bits 1 with [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.fill)

```py
rect_mask = pygame.mask.Mask((rect.width, rect.height)))
rect_mask.fill()
```

Use [`pygame.mask.Mask.overlap`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.overlap) to for the collision detection between Mask objects. The offset parameter of the method `overlap()` is the relative position of the *`othermask`* in relation to the [`pygame.mask.Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask) object.

e.g.:

object 1: `x1`, `y1`, `mask1`
object 2: `x2`, `y2`, `mask2`

```py
offset = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
if mask1.overlap(mask2, offset):
    print("hit")
```

See also [PyGame collision with masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks/57499484#57499484) and [Pygame mask collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077813/pygame-mask-collision/60078039#60078039).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `pygame.mask.Mask` using the `width` and `height` of the rect object:

```
playermask = pygame.mask.Mask((player.width, player.height))
playermask.fill()
```