# What is the correct way to resize an image in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, resize, image-resizing

I have an image in pygame and my code detects if this image is clicked on. It worked fine and I decided to resize the image, but when I did that the image randomly disappeared. Here was the code before the image disappeared:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
width = 500
height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
white = (255, 255, 255)
screen.fill(white)

pygame.display.set_caption('Aim Trainer')
target = pygame.image.load("aim target.png").convert_alpha()

x = 20  # x coordinate of image
y = 30  # y coordinate of image
screen.blit(target, (x, y))  # paint to screen
pygame.display.flip()  # paint screen one time
targetSize = pygame.transform.scale(target, (5, 3))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y positions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if target.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                print('clicked on image')
# loop over, quite pygame
pygame.quit()
```

and here is my code after:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
width = 500
height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
white = (255, 255, 255)
screen.fill(white)

pygame.display.set_caption('Aim Trainer')
target = pygame.image.load("aim target.png").convert_alpha()

x = 20  # x coordinate of image
y = 30  # y coordinate of image
pygame.display.flip()  # paint screen one time
targetSize = pygame.transform.scale(target, (5, 3))

screen.blit(targetSize, (x, y))  # paint to screen
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Set the x, y positions of the mouse click
            x, y = event.pos
            if target.get_rect().collidepoint(x, y):
                print('clicked on image')
# loop over, quite pygame
pygame.quit()
```

As you can see, the only thing that changed was me renaming `screen.blit(target, (x, y))` to `screen.blit(targetSize, (x, y))`, and me moving this line of code a few lines furthur down to avoid a 'TargetSize is not defined' error. But for some reason, this change makes the image disappear. The program still detects it when I click on the image, it's just that the image isn't visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to get the rectangle from the scaled iamge
2. [`pygame.Surface.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. A *Surface* is `blit` at a position on the screen. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the top left of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `topleft`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments).
3. Update the display after drawing the image

```py
targetSize = pygame.transform.scale(target, (5, 3))
target_rect = targetSize.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

screen.blit(targetSize, (x, y))
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if target_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                print('clicked on image')
```

Comment: @BluBalloon `target_rect = targetSize.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))`

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work now. How would I go about making the hitbox more precise, like a circle? (Or should I ask that on a seperate question?)

Comment: @BluBalloon A box is a box. Youi cannot make it mor "precise". However see [How do I detect collision in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame/65064907#65064907) and [PyGame collision with masks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57455811/pygame-collision-with-masks/57499484#57499484).